# Why my App Terminates when I click my iPhone for 2 seconds?

Tags: ios

1. I test my app on iPhone.
2. On Xcode 8.3, I have chosen Automatically manage signing. my account info about Entity Type is Company / Organization.
3. When my app was installed on my iPhone before 3 days it was running. But now when I open my app crashes after splash screen.
4. I found my certificate was revoked in the keychain.

That is all, thank you！

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a free developer program membership?  Apps installed using a free membership need to be reinstalled after a few days.

Comment: No,my company account cost $99.And generate iOS team PP expires in 11 months.